# Equipamiento vs equipmento

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, sustantivos

He oído ambos para describir cosas que son usados en cualquier industria, por ejemplo, equipamiento/equipmento para acampar o esquiar. ¿Son sinónimos perfectos o hay diferencias?

Comment: Existe realmente "equipmento"? Una búsqueda en google devuelve resultados para "Equipamiento" pero no "equipmento". Aparte, si miras en el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?w=diccionario) verás que solo puedes encontrar uno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La palabra `equipmento` no existe en el lenguaje español. Puedes buscar en [El sitio de la Real Academia Española](http://rae.es) para confirmar mis dichos. Podría decirse que es un calco del inglés, ya que en ese lenguaje **Equipamiento** se traduce como **Equipment**.

Comment: jajaj que tonto soy... pero por cierto he visto "equipmento" en algún lugar. tal vez se ha convertido en un cognado entendido

Comment: Que se use en internet no quiere decir que sea correcto en Español, aunque el uso hace el lenguaje y esas cosas son tomadas en cuenta muchas veces por la RAE, no necesariamente es asi.